# How to install iis 6.0 on windows xp-32?

Tags: iis-6, windows-xp, installation

well, according to what I've found googling around, it's imposible... (maybe with with windows xp 64...)

but I thought that maybe someone could find a way to achieve it, or at least some workaround...

http://www.iisanswers.com/IISFAQ.htm

http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.inetserver.iis&tid=14654991-875f-4cc6-a853-7e9f3bb96bc3&cat=en&lang=en&cr=&sloc=en-us&m=1&p=1

--
ps: I need to debug classic asp code, and my production environment is windows 2003, while my development machine is windows xp...

--
edit:
just to clarify, I can already debug classic asp code in iis 5 with vs 2003 and 2008, it's just that I stumbled upon a (very silly) bug that only appeared on iis 6 (when IIS 5 received and empty http status, it just assumed 200, while iis 6 kept asking for my credentials in an infinite loop, it was very silly in deed, but took me a lot of time -and cursing- to discover it)

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you want, but VMWare + an MSDN for Operating Systems subscription would make your life a whole lot easier, and the cost would likely be less than the time you spend tinkering with these unsupported configurations.

Answer (score 3):

IIS 6 cannot be installed on Win XP.  However, debugging classic ASP code is possible on Windows XP / IIS 5.1 using Visual Studio 2003 and up.  You will need to configure IIS 5.1 to "enable ASP server-side debugging" (disabled by default):

[IIS settings http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f1a6f781b9.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f1a6f781b9.png)

Here is a more detailed article on how to debug classic ASP pages in Visual Studio - [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/06/24/432308.aspx)

(NOTE: When running on XP Pro/IIS 5, you need to attach to dllhost.exe instead of w3wp.exe)

Comment: yes, I know, I already do a lot of debugging in iis 5, but I found a strange bug that only happens on IIS 6...

Comment: @opensas - Looks like you will need to install a version of Visual Studio on system that has Windows Server 2003 installed in order to attach the debugger to IIS 6.  You can do this on a virtual machine or a spare server.  It is commonly not advised to install Visual Studio onto production server equipment.

Answer (score 0):

You posting in your 2nd link is correct. And read the faq. That spells out why it can't be done.

One option you can do is have a virtual machine of Server 2003 running on your laptop.